# How to align left for a text outside a "float: right" table with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to align the text "**Legend**" lefts the table. For the margin, it may not work when the windows screen has been resized (responsive). I tried the `text-align: left` or `center` but it didn't work as my expected.

Actually, the `div` element can be changed by using another one or adding JS to make it work.

Here is the **Fiddle** link:
https://jsfiddle.net/h4bsp4or/

See the following screen-shot of how it should look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd92J.png

```css
.tdAlignTop {
  vertical-align: text-top !important;
}

.legendTable {
  border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
  width: auto;
  /*margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;*/
  float: right;
}

.legendTable span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.legendTable .legendTO {
  background-color: #A9D08E;
}

.legendTable .legendT {
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
}

.legendTable .legendM {
  background-color: #FF0039;
}

.legendTable .legendN {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
  <TD class=tdAlignTop>
  <DIV>Legend</DIV>
  <TABLE class=legendTable>
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendT></SPAN>T</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendM></SPAN>M</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendN></SPAN>N To L</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendTO></SPAN>T TO</TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

Comment: What's the error here?

Comment: The `Legend` text always in the left side of a page. However, it must be always at the left side of the table, please see the `JSFiddle` link.

Comment: Why didn't you use `text-align:right`?

Comment: @Rob: It will be at the **right** side of the `table`. I would like to make it be at the **left** side of only `table`.

Comment: Please see my answer below, you're floating your table, so you need to also float your legend div or add a wrapper around it and float that instead. (Best practice)

Comment: Yes but a little margin can fix that or you can wrap both elements in another div.

Comment: If the elements belong together, it would make more sense to have a single wrapper for them, as Rob has pointed out. Alternatively, [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example) could be used.

Comment: If I add a single wrapper for the `td`. It made other `td`s stay below that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in this way. Add

```
clear:both;
```

for the legend table. and

```
float:right and margin:[some] px;
```

for the div caption. It will stick the left side of the table top even on window resize.

```css
.tdAlignTop {
  vertical-align: text-top !important;
}

.legendTable {
  border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
  width: auto;
  clear:both;
  /*margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;*/
  float: right;
}

.legendTable span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.legendTable .legendTO {
  background-color: #A9D08E;
}

.legendTable .legendT {
  background-color: #A6A6A6;
}

.legendTable .legendM {
  background-color: #FF0039;
}

.legendTable .legendN {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
  <TD class=tdAlignTop>
  <DIV  style="float:right;margin-right:24px;">Legend</DIV>
  <TABLE class=legendTable>
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendT></SPAN>T</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendM></SPAN>M</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendN></SPAN>N To L</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <SPAN class=legendTO></SPAN>T TO</TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

Comment: If the data in the legend table has changed and becomes more longer than the previous ones so the `margin: [some] px` will not work. I am heading to find a way to prevent it from hard-coding.

Answer (score 0):

You're floating `.legendTable` when you should be floating a wrapper around what's inside `#tdAlignTop`.

```
.legend-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="legend-wrapper">
    <DIV>Legend</DIV>
    <TABLE class=legendTable>
      ...
    </TABLE>
</div>
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1hhya7xz/

Comment: You are required to post your code as an answer here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Comment: That's great. However, it made a regression to other my `td`s in my `table` (Other `td`s stay below that `td`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below code for your legend, however it wont be the best way:

`<DIV align="right">Legend</DIV>`

Comment: It will be at the **right** side of the `table`. I would like to make it be at the **left** side of only `table`.